# Shiny Server doesnt deploy app

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

We have installed Shiny Server and RStudio Server on a CentOs 7. We can see the sample-apps that come pre-loaded into it (sample-apps/hello/), which run absolutely fine.

However, when we copy+paste these same server.R and ui.R files into a new folder (sample-apps/new_hello) and try to run this new version, we get the following error:

```
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

We are also unable to run our own shiny apps which are already working on our own laptops. So it is not R-code related.

Are we missing a step here?

Comment: It was a library issue with RMySQL which was a leftover from a previous attempt

Comment: So, installing this library solved your problem???

Comment: Just check that shiny-server has permission to the right folders and it should be solved. For my case, RMySQL was installed on a folder that shiny-server was not able to access

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is my solution:

You should install all the R's libraries in the following folder:

```
"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
```

and then make sure that the user ***shiny*** has the permission to access it.

I hope it can help other users that still looking for a solution.